# Rails 4 caching and belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have `User` model and `Comment` model that `belongs_to :user`

I understand what to do when I want to cache user page with comments listed (via 'russian doll caching') - I do global `cache` block for entire user view and put inside many cache blocks for each of user's comment, and add `touch: true` for `belongs_to :user` association. So, when some comment changes, there is only 2 caches to update - for that comment, and for that user.

But now I need to cache comment view that looks like:

```
= comment.user.name
= comment.text
```

So we need update cache not only when this comment changed, but when user name changed. What is more appropriate way to do this?

My current solution is after save callback on user that makes `comment.update_all(updated_at: updated_at)` and wrapping view in `cache(comment)` block. But I don't like it because I want to detect only some fields change.

Another solution is to wrap view in `cache(comment, comment.user)` but I think it's worse because it does additional query for user.

Am I miss something obvious? What is your experience?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must to use `has_many :comments, autosave: true` in your `User` model.